# ete3 module on python3 - cannot import TreeStyle, faces, AttrFace, NodeStyle

Tags: python, python-3.x, etetoolkit, ete3

I a linux user and so far I've using ete3 in python2 succesfully.

I installed ete3 for python3 and there are certain modules that python3 can't find. I believe I have all the dependencies installed according to the instructions.

I can import ete3, and Tree from ete3 but not any other that I've using so far.

Any clues on how to resolve this?

```
~$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ete3
>>> from ete3 import Tree
>>> from ete3 import TreeStyle
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'TreeStyle'
>>> from ete3 import faces
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'faces'
>>> from ete3 import AttrFace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'AttrFace'
>>> from ete3 import NodeStyle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'NodeStyle'
```

Comment: Maybe you ran into this issue: https://github.com/etetoolkit/ete/issues/315

Comment: Aside: the fact your Python version line doesn't have a rider like "Continuum Analytics, Inc." or "packaged by conda-forge" or something makes it seem like you're not using the recommended conda installation approach.  One advantage of it is that the dependencies are automatically resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install the dependencies. The problem was that ete3 is not reporting properly the missing dependencies.

You can see which dependencies are missing with this code:

```
import ete3
ete3.__file__
```

I run it multiple times and install the packages that was complaining about each time until it finally worked!